# Browser ignore Cache-Control

Tags: amazon-s3, cache-control

I set a static file on Amazon S3 to use `Cache-Control: max-age: 259200, must-revalidate`. However, when I load a test page on my browser in Safari, the resource tracker shows it's getting the file from Amazon S3 even though it's supposed to be cached. What's going on? Do browsers have special caching rules I'm not aware of that override `Cache-Control`?